# How to set display property in flex css

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to change below the CSS to flex but not working. instead of display block and width 100%, I want to do in flex. What is the equal of display block and width 100% in flex?

```css
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.test1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: #3fd819;
}

.test2 {
  background-color: rgb(122, 117, 202);
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>
  <div class="test1">
<div class="test2">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
  1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
  make a type specimen book.
</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

[image]

Comment: @aerial301 `.test2` should not be using `display: flex;` because `.test2` is a flex-item of `.test1`.

Comment: @aerial301: Not working

Comment: It's unclear what, exactly, you want. To confirm, you want `.test1` and `.test2` to be the same size? Why have nested elements then? You should give the different elements their own `outline` and/or `background-color` and you should post a screenshot or visual example of what you want.

Comment: @Dai: Demo link Added. Please check in full page.

Comment: Your problem is `box-sizing` is causing the inner element to be slightly-wider than the parent btw

Answer (score 1):

You're over-thinking it. Assuming you can't change the markup, all you need is this:

```css
.test1 {
  border: 5px solid #3fd819;
  background-color: rgb(122, 117, 202);
}
.test2 {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="test1">
      <div class="test2">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
          1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
          make a type specimen book.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you anticipate having multiple `.test2` children of `div.test1` and you want them stacked vertically, then that's also simple:

```css
.test1 {
  border: 5px solid #3fd819;
  background-color: rgb(122, 117, 202);
}
.test2 {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="test1">
      <div class="test2">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
          1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
          make a type specimen book.
      </div>

      <div class="test2">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
          1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
          make a type specimen book.
      </div>

      <div class="test2">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
          1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
          make a type specimen book.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not use a display block. Please use flex

Comment: @sarann Why? You haven't explained why you need or want to use `flex`. Besides, _there is no reason to use `flex` **at all** if an element has only a single child. If your HTML is not representative of your real problem then you've just wasted all of our time...